# UNMAP domain from Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, joomla, server

I've got one domain and one subdomain:

> example.com, sub.example.com

I want to map an application web on subdomain and i do this with virtual host.
I added on server.xml the next line:
`<Host name="sub.example.com"  appBase="archive_webapps"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/>`

And i removed ROOT.war from webapps folder (under tomcat7).

In this way the `URL` `example.com` redirect to a blank page (instead `sub.domain.com`redirect correctly), but I want to un-map this domain from Tomcat (because I want to use another application such as `JOOMLA` for this domain).

How can i do this?

Thanks